# nature of the load connected to the electric power grid

Tags: power, impedance, load, stability, power-grid

I know that loads can be modeled either as constant impedance or as fixed power P and Q. I also know that the majority of the loads are constant impedance type but I don't know exactly the percentage. If I want to do a stability study, how can I model the aggregated load to connect to the grid? The whole as a constant impedance type or a mix of the two types? Which are examples of loads that absorb constant power?

Comment: A switched mode power supply can be seen as taking a constant power from the AC supply.

Comment: Motor drives in large industrial equipment, e.g. mills, conveyor belts draw constant power.